# Rest API query on Db created through Java app in Marklogic

Tags: rest, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have done a JSONDocMgr.write(docId, handle); in my java application. The json data is loaded from a file. I can see my document in http://localhost:8000/qconsole/, but the case is that I need to use REST services to query the DB.
The docId is /books/text.json, when I try to do a GET using postman http://localhost:8000/books/search?q=harry I'm getting Page Not Found. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: FileInputStream docStream = new FileInputStream("E:/Lara/text.json");
This how I read my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your document via REST see [/v1/documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents). For example:

```
curl -i --digest --user myuser:mypwd -X GET \
  'http://localhost:8000/v1/documents?uri=/books/text.json'
```

To search documents via REST see [/v1/search](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search).  For example:

```
curl -i --digest --user myuser:mypwd -X GET \
  'http://localhost:8000/v1/search?q=harry'
```

Make sure the port and username you use for REST matches the port and username you use in Java.

Comment: I see that http://localhost:8000/v1/search?q=harry searches the entire document list, can I be more specific about the document it searches for?

Comment: Yes, that endpoint lets you write lots of different types of queries. See [Using and Configuring Query Options](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search) in the REST API Guide for more information.

Comment: Also, you can use the Java Client API to [read your document](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_59305) and [do searches](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches).